# Как очистить консоль?

Tags: windows, java, eclipse, консоль

Не нашел в Гугле, поэтому обращаюсь к вам. Пример: вывод времени на консоль в реальном времени. Желательно-полегче.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А зачем очищать консоль? И напомню что могут быть (и есть) случаи когда консоль принципиально неочищаема - все зависит от типа терминала и оси.

Например если консоль/терминал типа VT100, то очистка консоли производится стандартным ESCAPE кодом: `Esc[2J` ([источник](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php))

Виндовая консоль не поддерживает ансишные искейп коды, так что ничего лучшего [Backspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace) не придумать (ну разве что выдавать [CLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cls_(command)) на shell DOS/Windows).

В общем как ни делай, а все криво.

Comment: Как альтернатива Backspace, можно просто сдвигать консоль на N строк.

Answer (score 1):

Так в принципе работает, но не думаю что это хороший пример:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.print(formatter.format(new Date()));
        for (;;){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.print('\r');
                System.out.print(formatter.format(new Date()));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня не сработало (Win 7, Eclipse)

Comment: а в чем проблема?

Comment: Главное-ОЧИСТКА КОНСОЛИ

Comment: @rberla, да Вы что?! неужели?! а как мы должны были этого догадаться? данный реквест разбивается на две части, гуглите лучше и с энтузиазмом

Comment: В данном коде очистка консоли отсутствует.Как можно догадаться по недвусмысленной теме, главное-именно очистка консоли!

Comment: @rberla, Вы какую консоль имеете в виду? 

Окошко для ввода-вывода программы в Eclipse,

окно CMD в Windows

или что?

Очистить все строки и установть курсор (куда?) или одну строку, куда у Вас дата первый раз выводилась?

Вы вопрос толком сформулируйте, что увидеть хотите?

Answer (score -2):

cout << '\x08' - В С/С++ так. Думаю, Java мало чем отличается. Суть в том, что в stdout надо послять backspace столько раз, сколько нужно. Соответственно, гуглить надо код клавиши.

Comment: Я думаю, в этом случае java довольно далеко удалилась от С

Comment: Возможно, но не в работе с консолью.